# Cannot call value of non-function type

Tags: ios, swift

Having issues trying to convert this to Swift 3.0.

I have:

```
public typealias CustomCompletionBlock = (_ image: UIImage?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
public var completionBlock : CustomCompletionBlock!
```

Later on in my code I want to set `completionBlock` e.g.:

```
self.completionBlock(image: nil, error: error)
```

But I get the error ***"Cannot call value of non-function type"***. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

In `CustomCompletionBlock` signature,

```
public typealias CustomCompletionBlock = (_ image: UIImage?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
```

you have specified `_` as the **external parameter name** for `image` and `error` variables. This means while calling `CustomCompletionBlock` you don't have to specify any parameter names. `image` and `error` are **internal parameter names** i.e. they must only be used within closure definition.

So you must call it like:

```
self.completionBlock(nil, error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call it like this:

```
self.completionBlock(nil, error)
```